# How to select a proxy for CURL for https website?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, https, proxy

I'm trying to connect to a website using `CURL` on `localhost`, I tried many proxies but most of them didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
$url= 'https://stubhub.com';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

//certificate
$cacert='C:/xampp/cacert.pem';
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );

//SSL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

//Cookies
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,__DIR__."/cookie.txt");

//User-Agent
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );

//Proxy
$proxy = '50.115.194.97:8080';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 443);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);


//Errors
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$data = curl_exec( $curl );
$info = curl_getinfo( $curl );
$error = curl_error( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$allInfo = array($data, Info, $error);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($allInfo);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get the following response:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://stubhub.com/
            [content_type] => 
            [http_code] => 0
            [header_size] => 0
            [request_size] => 0
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 20.203
            [namelookup_time] => 0
            [connect_time] => 0
            [pretransfer_time] => 0
            [size_upload] => 0
            [size_download] => 0
            [speed_download] => 0
            [speed_upload] => 0
            [download_content_length] => -1
            [upload_content_length] => -1
            [starttransfer_time] => 0
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [redirect_url] => 
            [primary_ip] => 
            [certinfo] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_port] => 0
            [local_ip] => 
            [local_port] => 0
        )

    [2] => Failed to connect to 50.115.194.97 port 8080: Timed out
)
```

I tried with proxies that supports `https`, cookies and those with `443` port.

Is there is an API/library for this purpose?

Comment: 50.115.194.97 appears to be a public proxy which is dead.

Comment: @BhaskarChoudhary, How to get fresh proxies and make sure it's not dead?

Comment: To make sure the proxy is not dead, you have to load all proxies in an array, then in a loop use the proxy and try to load example.com. If an error occurs while trying to load example.com, check if that error is "Timed out". This way, you can eliminate dead proxies from your list.

Comment: Can you test a working proxy with the above website?

Comment: You have to create a new question for it and provide me the link .

<?php
$proxy_arr = [
 ["ip"=>"0.0.0.0", "port"=>"8888"],
 ["ip"=>"1.1.1.1", "port"=>"9999"],
];
$working_proxies=[];

foreach($proxy_arr as $proxy){
 $url= 'https://stubhub.com';
 $curl = curl_init();
 ...
 curl_close( $curl );
 if($error == ''){
  $working_proxies[] = $proxy;
 }
}

var_dump($working_proxies);

Comment: @BhaskarChoudhary, I don't mean code snippet, I mean if you have a working proxy, Could you test the code using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of open proxy apis.

For example:
gimmeproxy.com/api/getProxy?post=true&supportsHttps=true&maxCheckPeriod=7200&protocol=http

It looks like the proxy you are trying to use is down (not working).

As for me, I built the proxy parser and agregator for our projects. It is getting proxies from a bunch of open proxy lists, saves them to the database and checks them in the loop.
It became a very useful tool for us.

Comment: Ho do you check if the proxy is working before using it with CURL?

Comment: I visited that page and copied the proxy with the port, But I get  `Recv failure: Connection was reset` and sometimes `Failed to connect to 46.149.80.207 port 8888: Timed out`